# Parse Java enum file with a certain annotation

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, javaparser

This is what I want to do:
Given some enum files, filter out the ones with @someAnnotation in comment or as a class annotation, the grab the names of enum fields from AST. Maybe using Java Parser.

But I wasn't sure how to do it exactly.

Comment: Do you need to parse the source, or could you use the loaded java class (with reflection?)